# Can not understand behavior of gulp.src()

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Here is my code:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
$ = require('gulp-load-plugins')(),

module.exports = function(options) {
gulp.task('test', function () {

    gulp.src('external/bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));

    });
};
```

This string gulp.dest('dest/') will save file _bootstrap.scss in 'dest/' folder.

If I change the string

`gulp.src('external/bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss')`

to string

`gulp.src('external/*/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss')`

then string

```
gulp.dest('dest/')
```

will save file _bootstrap.scss in dest/bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets folder.

Can you explain and give me the link where to read about why in first case we have no lots of folder inside dest folder, and in the second case there are lots of folder inside dest folder?

If I understand correctly, in the second case, glob pattern will be converted to array of full files paths. It means that in my example glob nodejs module will convert glob pattern 'external/*/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss' to
array ['external/bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss']. So why do I have lots of nested folders inside 'dest/' folder in second case, but have no nested folders inside 'dest/' folder in first case?

Comment: Did the answer below help?

Answer (score 1):

Well indeed it is a little weird, since very implicit behaviour of node-glob. But in fact it is what you want to expect. For example think of the case you have multiple folders in `external` which will both have files `bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss')`. Then you can't save two files with the same name in your dest.

Without having looked into node-glob source, I think it mitigates this case by chopping of the files path after `/*/` and will automatically attach it to your `dest` path.

Having said that is implicit behaviour, you can easily avoid it by assigning the array yourself `gulp.src(['firstfile.js'])` if you really need the array or want to add files in the future.

Since Gulp docs don't offer too much info on globbing patterns, I found those links to be the best help. [Read up on node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) and [Gulp on smashing](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/06/11/building-with-gulp/).